# For web scraping through python, when should I use an html parser instead of lxml? Which is better and why?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, lxml

While I was trying to read Amazon's data, I noticed little difference in the outputs when I used an lxml parser instead of html. Which one should I prefer and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using BeautifulSoup for parsing? If so then read the documentation.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers

Comment: I don't know why I missed this. Thank you.
This helped.